# Java – How can I Log into a Website with HtmlUnit?

Tags: java, authentication, web, passwords, htmlunit

I am writing a Java program to log into the website my school uses to post grades.

This is the url of the login form: https://ma-andover.myfollett.com/aspen/logon.do

This is the HTML of the login form:

```
<form name="logonForm" method="post" action="/aspen/logon.do" autocomplete="off"><div><input type="hidden" name="org.apache.struts.taglib.html.TOKEN" value="30883f4c7e25a014d0446b5251aebd9a"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="userEvent" name="userEvent" value="930">
<input type="hidden" id="userParam" name="userParam" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="operationId" name="operationId" value="">
<input type="hidden" id="deploymentId" name="deploymentId" value="ma-andover">
<input type="hidden" id="scrollX" name="scrollX" value="0">
<input type="hidden" id="scrollY" name="scrollY" value="0">
<input type="hidden" id="formFocusField" name="formFocusField" value="username">
<input type="hidden" name="mobile" value="false">
<input type="hidden" name="SSOLoginDone" value="">
<center>
<img src="images/spacer.gif" height="15" width="1">

<script language="JavaScript">
document.forms[0].elements['deploymentId'].value = 'ma-andover';
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
$(function()
{
$('form').attr('autocomplete', 'off');
var name = $('#username');
var password = $('#password');
name.attr('autocomplete', 'off');
password.attr('autocomplete', 'off');
if (name.val() == '')
{
password.attr('disabled','disabled');
}
});
</script>

<img src="images/spacer.gif" height="30" width="1">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tbody><tr>
<td>
<div id="logonDetailContainer" class="logonDetailContainer">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

<tbody><tr>
<td>
<label style="text-align: center; margin-bottom: 0px">Andover Public Schools</label>
<img src="images/spacer.gif" height="10" width="1">
<hr class="logonHorizontalRule">
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>
<img src="images/spacer.gif" height="10" width="1">


<input type="text" name="fakeuser" style="display: none">
<input type="password" name="fakepassword" style="display: none">

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="labelCell">

<label>Login ID</label>
<input type="text" name="username" tabindex="1" value="" onkeypress="$('#password').prop('disabled', false)" id="username" class="logonInput" autocomplete="off">

&nbsp;

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="labelCell">

<label>Password</label>
<input id="password" type="password" name="password" tabindex="2" value="" class="logonInput" autocomplete="off" disabled="disabled">

<a href="javascript:EmbeddedPopup.popupManager.open('passwordRecovery.do?isSecondary=false&amp;deploymentId=ma-andover', 400, 400, 100)" tabindex="5" style="float: right">
I forgot my password
</a>


</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="1" class="logonTopPadding" style="float: left">
<input type="submit" tabindex="3" value="Log On" class="log-button">
</td>
</tr>

</tbody></table>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

</center>
<script>
setTimeout(function(){window.location.reload(true);}, 1800000);
</script>
</form>
```

I am trying to use the following code to log in:

```
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class LoginAttempt {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

            HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://ma-andover.myfollett.com/aspen/logon.do"); 
            HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("logonForm"); 
            form.getInputByName("username").setValueAttribute("myUsername"); //works fine 
            form.getInputByName("password").setValueAttribute("myPassword"); //does not work 

            page = form.getInputByValue("Log On").click(); //works fine

            System.out.println(page.asText());
    } 

}
```

The program fills the username box and clicks the "Log On" button, but it does not fill the password box.  What can I change to make this program work?  I suspect the "type = 'password'" attribute of the password box has something to do with the problem, but please correct me if I am wrong. Any help is appreciated.  Thank you very much.

The target page: https://ma-andover.myfollett.com/aspen/home.do

And this is my output, in case it might be helpful:

```
Aspen: Log On

Aspen

    About Aspen
Andover Public Schools
Login ID myUsername  
Password I forgot my password
Log On

Copyright © 2003-2014 Follett School Solutions. All rights reserved.
Follett Corporation Follett Software Company Aspen Terms of Use

You must enter a password.
OK
```

Comment: which version of htmlunit are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The password field is disabled until you type something in the `username` field.
By setting the value in username doesn't trigger the event that manages the enabling of password field.

The below works

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    try {
        HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient
                .getPage("https://ma-andover.myfollett.com/aspen/logon.do");
        HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("logonForm");
        form.getInputByName("username").setValueAttribute("myUsername"); 
        HtmlInput passWordInput = form.getInputByName("password");
        passWordInput.removeAttribute("disabled");
        passWordInput.setValueAttribute("myPassword"); 

        page = form.getInputByValue("Log On").click(); // works fine

        System.out.println(page.asText());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        webClient.close();
    }
}
```

The output is

```
Aspen: Log On

Aspen

    About Aspen
Andover Public Schools
Login ID myUsername  
Password I forgot my password
Log On

Copyright © 2003-2014 Follett School Solutions. All rights reserved.
Follett Corporation Follett Software Company Aspen Terms of Use

Invalid login.  
OK
```

Comment: Thank you for answering my question so quickly.  The username box was filled in before the password box, so I don't see why it was disabled, but your line, "passWordInput.removeAttribute("disabled");" seems to have worked.  The login now works properly.

Comment: @alkis I tried your code but it throws a version error.`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0` .I am using java 1.7 and the `<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
</dependency>` .What can be the cause?Any help is appreciated

Comment: @Ricky This a very old answer. I don't remember the versions I used. Please open a new question with the versions that you are using and the code. Someone else might have experienced the same problem and might have an easy solution.

Answer (score 2):

To automatically handle the JavaScript, you should use `type()` instead.

```
try (WebClient webClient = new WebClient()) {

    HtmlPage page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage("https://ma-andover.myfollett.com/aspen/logon.do"); 
    HtmlForm form = page.getFormByName("logonForm"); 
    form.getInputByName("username").type("myUsername"); 
    form.getInputByName("password").type("myPassword"); 

    page = form.getInputByValue("Log On").click();

    System.out.println(page.asText());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient())    
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("url");

((HtmlTextInput) page.getHtmlElementById("usernameID")).setText("Username");
page.getHtmlElementById("passwordID").setAttribute("value","Password");

page.getElementsByTagName("button").get(0).click();

System.out.println(page.asText());
```

I clicked the button that way because my button doesn't have an id, name, or value, but luckily its the only button on the page. So I just get all the button tags (all one of them) and select the first element in the List to click.