# Log in to Fidelity using JSoup and Java

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup

I am trying to log in to my personal Fidelity account to scrape some data once logged in i.e. account balance. I am using Java with the JSoup library, and using this resource as a guide [How to login to a website using Jsoup (Java)](https://joelmin.blogspot.com/2016/04/how-to-login-to-website-using-jsoup-java_4.html). I am able to hit the server, however getting a discouraging message from Fidelity. Might anyone have any ideas as to why, and how I could resolve this issue? I'm wondering if this is a me issue or a Fidelity issue. Thanks a ton in advance!

My code...

```java
package com.investmeinc.fs;

import org.jsoup.Connection;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import java.util.HashMap;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.investmeinc.fs")
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

        String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36";
        String loginFormUrl = "https://digital.fidelity.com/prgw/digital/login/full-page?AuthRedUrl=https://oltx.fidelity.com/ftgw/fbc/ofsummary/defaultPage";
        String loginActionUrl = "https://login.fidelity.com/ftgw/Fas/Fidelity/RtlCust/Login/Response/dj.chf.ra";
        String username = "<username>";
        String password = "<password>";

        HashMap<String, String> cookies = new HashMap<>();
        HashMap<String, String> formData = new HashMap<>();

        try {
            Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect(loginFormUrl).method(Connection.Method.GET).userAgent(USER_AGENT).execute();
            cookies.putAll(loginForm.cookies()); // save the cookies, this will be passed on to next request

            formData.put("DEVICE_PRINT", "version%3D3.5.2_2%26pm_fpua%3Dmozilla%2F5.0+(x11%3B+linux+x86_64%3B+rv%3A41.0)+gecko%2F20100101+firefox%2F41.0%7C5.0+(X11)%7CLinux+x86_64");
            formData.put("SSN", username);
            formData.put("SavedIdInd", "N");
            formData.put("PIN", password);

            Connection.Response homePage = Jsoup.connect(loginActionUrl)
                    .cookies(cookies)
                    .data(formData)
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .userAgent(USER_AGENT)
                    .execute();

            System.out.println(homePage.parse().html());
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  
}
```

Fidelity response...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
 <head> 
  <title>We are Sorry.  There was a Technical Issue.</title> 
    </style> 
 </head> 
 <body> 
  <div class="container"> 
   <div class="slimNavBar"> 
    <img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"> 
   </div> 
   <div class="content"> 
    <h1>We are Sorry. There was a Technical Issue.</h1> 
    <p>We are currently aware of an issue with some 3rd party browser plugins that are causing issues with access to the Fidelity website. Please try running your browser in incognito mode - or using an alternative browser as we work with the 3rd parties to resolve the issue.</p> 
    <p>If you continue to receive this page please contact customer support and provide them the reference number below.</p> 
    <p></p> 
    <p>Reference Error: 18.16b72d17.1577490834.4123d1d9</p> 
    <p><a href="https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__www.fidelity.com_customer-2Dservice_faqs-2Dtechnical-2Dsupport&amp;d=DwMGAg&amp;c=96ZbZZcaMF4w0F4jpN6LZg&amp;r=RF0iETrjFEtmK4R05mAKW62xvQwOxm_-CPimNHozwuY&amp;m=gdeanQALapHLAzFN2UUMQX3zmZ0MMtyTEfGNRFzQJC0&amp;s=GDiw6-EzN5g5AYTBUAcSm_eH24scFNz1kcmxzq9FBJg&amp;e=">Customer Service FAQs: Technical Support</a></p> 
    <p><a href="https://urldefense.proofpoint.com/v2/url?u=https-3A__www.fidelity.com_customer-2Dservice_phone-2Dnumbers_overview&amp;d=DwMGAg&amp;c=96ZbZZcaMF4w0F4jpN6LZg&amp;r=RF0iETrjFEtmK4R05mAKW62xvQwOxm_-CPimNHozwuY&amp;m=gdeanQALapHLAzFN2UUMQX3zmZ0MMtyTEfGNRFzQJC0&amp;s=KuqAtDRmmQPm-z0C8VAyenCbNTdbN2yUcNj_oLDr0Hs&amp;e="> Customer-Service Numbers</a></p> 
   </div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="footer"> 
   <img alt="" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"> 
   <p>Copyright 1998-2017 FMR LLC. All Rights Reserved.</p> 
  </div>   
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you mind to include the status code? Also, I think the response is giving you some guidance. Maybe you can change the User-Agent header in JSoup and try again? It seems they have banned the JSoup-by-default User-Agent, at least that's what the response made me think.

Comment: The only thing I can think of on this is that there's a missing header value. It's rather suspicious for a financial site that there's no obvious CSRF token in the request, so this could be sent as a header if the form submission is being caught by the code on the page. In which case you'd see that in the headers section of the browser console's network tab for that request.

Comment: Also, it's worth mentioning that most financial institutions actively try to thwart scraping code like this and prohibit the use of scrapers in their TOS.

Comment: You could use a more popular library like HtmlUnit, and some relevant topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496365/java-how-can-i-log-into-a-website-with-htmlunit

Comment: *Update* Thanks for all the suggestions! So I decided to change my approach. Instead of trying to log in and screen scrape my Fidelity account data, I decided to switch brokers and use TDAmeritrade's account APIs. Their APIs are great to work with and solved that particular problem, however presented another... I prefer trading on Fidelity's mobile app as opposed to TD's  : /